# Calendário Android por semanas e meses

Tags: java, android

Estou a trabalhar com calendários em Android. O objetivo é mostrar o calendário por **semanas** e por **meses**. Mas o calendário que estou a utilizar só me permite a visualização por **mes**.

*Código xml*

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_centerInParent = "true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
            app:mcv_selectionColor="#00F"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*Activity onde este é invocado*

```
    MaterialCalendarView materialCalendarView = (MaterialCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    materialCalendarView.state().edit()
            .setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY)
            .setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
            .setMinimumDate(CalendarDay.from(1900, 1, 1))
            .setMaximumDate(CalendarDay.from(2100, 12, 31))
            .setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.MONTHS)
            .commit();

    //quando um dos dias é selecionado
    materialCalendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivitySelecionado.class);
            enviarDados(intent, date);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

A partir do que tenho aqui é possível configurar o calendário para ter a vista por **semanas**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para "*ter a vista por semanas*" você precisa modificar o valor do parâmetro do método `setCalendarDisplayMode` para `CalendarMode.WEEKS`.

Basicamente alterar de:

```
setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.MONTHS)
```

para:

```
setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.WEEKS)
```